IEnumerable<IRepository> returns a different instance then when asking for a (for example) IUserRepository
I'm currently trying to preload some data. The details for it are not important but the structure for it looks something like this:
public interface IRepository
{
    public Task PreLoadData();
}

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository
{
    public List<User> Users { get; }
    // other instance specific methods.
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public List<User> Users { get; private set; }

    public async Task PreLoadData()
    {
        Users = await GetUsers();
    }
}

When I register these as services.AddScoped<IRepository, UserRepository>(), both IEnumerable<IRepository> and IUserRepository can be injected into a class. However; they are separate instances: When calling .PreLoadData() on a member of the IEnumerable<IRepository>, the data is not loaded when I inject the specific interface version later on. If I inject the entire IEnumerable however, all those members are filled. I also tried registering as Singleton, but that didn't work either.
When I register these as services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(), the IEnumerable<IRepository> remains empty.
The reason I want this is so I can call the following early on to ensure some data is loaded:
public class DataPreLoader
{
    private IEnumerable<IRepository> _repositories;

    public DataPreLoader(IEnumerable<IRepository> repositories)
    {
        _repositories = repositories;
    }

    public async Task PreloadAllData()
    {
        foreach(var repository in _repositories)
        {
            await repository.PreLoadData();
        }
    }
}

Is there anyway I can make sure the IEnumerable<IDataLoader> receives the same instances as those injected when using IUserRepository?
(ps. I used repository as an example as it seemed to me most would be familiar with this. In the true implementation it's something else entirely. So comments about not loading data from a database this way, while appreciated, won't be necessary)

Unrelated, but are you sure you want this? It looks to me as if that would be a use case for a preheated cache.

That's also a good suggestion, I hadn't considered that yet!


When I register these as services.AddScoped<IRepository, UserRepository>(), both IEnumerable and IUserRepository can be injected into a class.

This is not true. Through that registration, you could resolve IRepository or IEnumerable<IRepository> from the service provider, but not IUserRepository.
To be able to do that, you must also have a services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>() registration, but that is a completely separate service registration from the perspective of the service container.
The consequence of that, is that you would receive a different instance, within the same scope, dependant on whether you resolved IUserRepository or IRepository (or IEnumerable<IRepository> for that matter). The fact that the implementation type is the same is irrelevant.
For example:
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScoped<IRepository, UserRepository>()
    .AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>()
    .BuildServiceProvider()
    .CreateScope().ServiceProvider;

var a = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository>();
var b = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IRepository>>();
var c = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserRepository>();

a == b.Single(); // true
a == c // false


To achieve what you're after, you could register the concrete implementation type (UserRepository), and factory functions to resolve from each interface e.g.
new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScoped<UserRepository>()
    .AddScoped<IRepository, UserRepository>(
        sp => sp.GetRequiredService<UserRepository>())
    .AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(
        sp => sp.GetRequiredService<UserRepository>());


Perfect, that makes sense to me. I kind of hoped there would be a way to do it with only one registration though unfortunately that seems to not be the case.
